# Dealing with curly brace soup

Tags: c#, programming-practices

I've programmed in both C# and VB.NET for years, but primarily in VB. I'm making a career shift toward C# and, overall, I like C# better.

One issue I'm having, though, is curly brace soup. In VB, each structure keyword has a matching close keyword, for example:

```vb
Namespace ...
    Class ...
        Function ...
            For ...
                Using ...
                    If ...
                        ...
                    End If
                    If ...
                        ...
                    End If
                End Using
            Next
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

The same code written in C# ends up very hard to read:

```csharp
namespace ... {
    class ... {
        function ... {
            for ... {
                using ... {
                    if ... {
                        ...
                    }
                    if ... {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
            // wait... what level is this?
        }
    }
}
```

Being so used to VB, I'm wondering if there's a technique employed by c-style programmers to improve readability and to ensure that your code ends up in the correct "block". The above example is relatively easy to read, but sometimes at the end of a piece of code I'll have 8 or more levels of curly braces, requiring me to scroll up several pages to figure out which brace ends the block I'm interested in.

Comment: I know this may sound preachy, and maybe you have special conditions that require it (because yeah, *sometimes* it's necessary - thankfully such times should be rare), but *usually* *"...8 or more levels of curly braces, requiring me to scroll up several pages to figure out which brace ends the block I'm interested in"* means the code needs some serious refactoring and cleanup.

Comment: One thing I've seen done, and I've taken to doing, is at the end of a curly brace, I'll add a comment about it.  Something like `// End's using X statement`.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner is spot on about the fact that your control flow is a mess and needs to be redone. That said, I think you're complaining more about the curly braces than the scoping and I would say you just need to get used to it. Learning a language with significantly different syntax than you're used to definitely looks like soup for a bit of a while, but with practice that goes away. You just need to buckle down and deal until your brain starts to process the syntax more naturally, you'll get there.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - I need to cleanup a lot of COM objects in a COM interop situation. I'm using the technique suggested in this article: http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-com-interop. This easily creates two or three layers. When you stack the for loop, function, class and namespace on top of that (along with an if statement) you easily get to several layers of braces.

Comment: @Cyborgx37: Ok that's fair. I normally wouldn't include the namespace or class level braces because I usually don't have more than one per file making it easier to handle them. Within a function is where I really start keeping track and I start to consider refactoring when the depth reaches 5 or 6, but sometimes it varies, and yeah, sometimes refactoring is actually more trouble than cleaning up one level of braces.

Comment: @TyrionLannister - And those can be some of the fastest comments to go out of sync with what they belong to...  I think if I was going to have something like that, I'd prefer it to be auto-generated (at display-time only, not persisted) by the IDE.

Comment: @TyrionLannister - I do the commenting at the final curly brace, too, but I keep it to the namespace, class, and method levels.  In C# I also try to always use the /// comments at the beginning of methods and properties.

Comment: A good IDE can do this for you, a tool-tip showing the other matching side.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio - check out the extension Indent Guides (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30)

Comment: +1. AFAICR This is mentioned in *Code Complete*, where it says this is a drawback of curly-brace languages and an advantage of languages like VB

Comment: I have a very simple solution.

Don't use curly braces.

No, really, I mean it. My philosophy for the last several years is that if I need to add a curly brace, then it's time for a new method. I get more descriptive code that way and it's easier to debug, as I can skip over things I don't care about. Now, yes, this isn't a hard and fast rule, but pretty close. I rarely have a method that's more than 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Put your starting curly brace in the same "rank" as your ending one, like this:

```
namespace ... 
{
    class ... 
    {
        function ... 
        {
            for ... 
            {
                using ... 
                {
                    if ... 
                    {
                        ...
                    }
                    if ... 
                    {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
            // It's the `function` level!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree.  Egyptian brackets give me a headache.

Comment: Also, most IDEs (probably) highlight a brace's partner when you click on it.

Comment: @TyrionLannister: Thanks for finally giving me a term for that style! I never had a good name for them other than "mis-aligned braces".

Comment: @StuperUser - Hunting for the single highlighted character is what drove me to post this question in the first place. :)

Comment: @Cyborgx37: Does your IDE have a "Go to matching brace" feature? Usually bound to a key shortcut that automatically moves your cursor to the brace that matches the currently highlighted one.

Comment: Thanks. In the past (with smaller projects) I always found that style to be ugly (filling my screen with "wasted" whitespace). I hadn't considered the layout advantages.

Comment: Funny, it didn't even occur to me that one would write C# without doing this. Good job noticing an obvious duh that would fly past most C# devs

Comment: Thanks, I think a combination of changing my brace style and implementing some of @JimmyHoffa's refactoring suggestions may ease the affliction. At least it feels better than commenting every single close brace in my code.

Comment: +1, imo, far easier to read code when braces are on their own line.

Comment: Gotta say, I don't see how this makes it any easier. Either way you just look up the screen at the brace's indent level till you get to a keyword. And with all those extra lines you now have further to look.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: That term was popularized on SE (and elsewhere) by [this deleted Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2349378/978917), which you should check out if you're interested in useful terms. (Those without 10k rep on Stack Overflow can visit [this blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) instead; it has the top 30 answers to that question, though without the fun comment-threads.)

Comment: Yoda conditions, Tie-fighter else.  Programmers are obsessed with Star Wars.  That post also contains the [highest-voted comment ever written.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined#comment2328409_2353436)

Comment: Isn't this the default formatting used in Visual Studio at least since 2008? `Ctrl+E, D`. I find it odd that programmers shy away from it.

Answer (score 14):

- Depending on your IDE: put your cursor at the open/close brace and it'll highlight both that and the corresponding brace.
- Collapse the block and it shows you where it opens/closes.
- Write smaller code blocks. Seriously. Check out `Clean Code`, and never run into this problem again (and have more readable/maintainable code).

One note, the following is valid c# syntax that might help your particular situation:

```
using (var type = new MyDisposable1())
using (var type2 = new MyDisposable2())
{
    /* do what you will with type2 and type2 */
}
```

Comment: Hunting for the single highlighted character is what drove me to post this question in the first place.

Comment: @Cyborgx37: Hence point 3. If your entire code block fits on screen, you never have to hunt. In most/all of the classes I write, the only pairs of braces that don't fit on screen are namespace/class.

Comment: What you suggest in points 1 & 2 is what I do now... but this requires that I leave the place where I'm coding and start manipulating my view of the code to figure out where to put the next line. Point 3 is well-taken, but not always possible, especially if your code requires several layers of `using` blocks (see http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-com-interop)

Comment: @Cyborgx37: See my edit.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 If you pick a color that stands out from everything else (I used purple background and white text for a while, IIRC) then there is no need to hunt for the matching brace - it practically SCREAMS at you "I'm **HERE**!".

Answer (score 6):

In general, when it gets hard to match braces in whatever style -  it probably means the method is too long and should be re-factored.

Answer (score 5):

A common convention is to add a comment after the closing brace to indicate the structure that it's closing:

```
if {
   ...
} // end if

while (condition) {
   ...
} // end while
```

etc.  I've never warmed to this convention myself, but some people find it helpful.

Comment: I have seen people do this, and when they swap/change the begining of the block (change a `while` to a `for`, swap to `if` statements) they *almost NEVER* remember to update the closing comments, rendering them **worse** than useless. This convention is probably only going to be useful if you can force yourself to maintain the comments every time the nature of the matching `{` changes.

Comment: Yeah, I've done some of this, but it's a lot of extra work (and noise). I was hoping there'd be something more straightforward.

Comment: @Cyborgx37: It might seem to be a lot of extra work, but it's fully worth it for readability, and it "almost" follows along with VB syntax.  So, coming from that background, it should be almost second nature. :D

Comment: Comments should only explain *why* never *what* or *how* as the code does both of those and relying on comments to explain either of them means the code is hard to read which is a sign the code should be corrected not commented.

Comment: This makes me wonder why no one has written an editor that displays these comments, but doesn't actually include them in the code..

Comment: Because editors can do something much more useful: they can 1) indent code automatically based on syntax; 2) flag syntax errors as you type and 3) implement folding so that deep nesting can be viewed as an abbreviated, collapsed structure resembling a summary.

Comment: I see a market for an IDE (-plugin) that automagically creates and maintains those comments.

Comment: Like I said, I don't use the convention myself, even though it would have saved my bacon on more than one occasion.  It just adds too much clutter.  Lining up opening and closing braces (which has the benefit of giving the code a little vertical breathing space) does the trick for me.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: I think a better rule for comments is that they should provide _clarity_. Usually that means answering "why", but it can also mean other things. Don't get so caught up in dogma that it stops you from doing things that actually help, such as occasionally adding a comment to a closing brace that is far removed from its opening brace.

Comment: @BryanOakley you missed the part about when you need to comment the what then the code needs to be corrected, a comment because a curly brace is far removed from it's opening brace is an obvious sign the scope is too large and should be refactored to minimize the chance of someone mistaking the scope and implementing bugs. It's not dogma to say oversized scopes are hard to read and cause bugs. Worst case scenario you simply take some of the code in that scope and move it to other methods to increase the scope's readability if you can't minimize what it's doing

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: I agree that a brace that is far removed is a sign it needs to be refactored. Sometimes, however, that is simply not a practical option. In a situation where you can't refactor, a comment is a reasonable compromise IMO.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to tough it out with the braces. Eventually they will become second nature to you and you will be wondering how you ever lived without them.

Make sure they are indented appropriately though, and that some spacing convention is being followed (doesn't matter which).

Comment: A year later, and this advice rings true. :)

Answer (score 4):

I remove 2 levels of nesting by collapsing the namespace and class scopes horizontally.  Notice the methods are flush with the left edge of the screen. I don't see the point in losing 2 levels of indentation in every file.

After that it's rare you'll ever have nesting more than 4 levels deep.

```
namespace FooNameSpace {
class Foo {

public void bar()
{
    while(true)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void fooBar()
{
    foreach(var item in FooList)
    {
        foreach(var b in item.Bars)
        {
            if(b.IsReady)
            {
                bar();
            }
            bar();
        }
        bar();
    }
}

}}//end class, namespace
```

Comment: I like this idea, but Visual Studio doesn't seem to support it (at least, 2008. We're upgrading to 2012 by the end of the year, so here's hoping)

Comment: @Cyborgx37. I edit the text externally in VIM so it's not a problem. But in Visual Studio do: Control+A, then hit the "indent less" button. Only do it for new files. Don't bother with existing files as it will mess up the diff-comparisons in source control.

Comment: Typing in closing brackets/braces initiates an auto-format by VS but you can always hit CTRL+z to refuse its suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I recently decided to try and formalize two rules about flow control constructs that basically go like this:

- You should have nothing but *necessary* code-flow constructs
- You should make the code-flow constructs as small as possible

For exactly the reasons you have mentioned and are clearly aware of, I think these are great rules to follow. There are a couple simple techniques you can employ to accomplish them:

- Exit scope as soon as you can (this includes the scope of loops as well as functions)
- Watch for elses that could be mitigated by exiting the function from the preceding if and apply the scope exiting technique as I mentioned
- Reverse your conditional checks when the code inside an if is great than that outside
- Factor code inside of a loop out to another method when the size of the loop grows to obscure the rest of the method
- Watch for any scopes that only contain another scope, for instance a function whose entire scope is filled by an if with nothing outside of the if

I detailed [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/172905/use-an-else-after-exception-or-not/172910#172910) examples of how not following these can end up with you doing as you said and putting code in the wrong code block, which is *bad* and an easy cause of bugs cropping up during maintenance.

Comment: Thanks, there may be a block or two that I could refactor out. It will help, but it's hard to refactor out several nested `using` blocks.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 actually using blocks can be inlined if they're nested fulfilling scopes, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329739/nested-using-statements-in-c-sharp it basically works like single line flow control constructs how you can if (true) doSomething(); you can also if (true) if (somethingElse) if (otherThings) { doThis(); doThat(); doWhatever(); } and the ifs nest as you expect (DON'T WRITE CODE LIKE THAT FOR THE LOVE OF GOD, JUST DO THIS WITH USINGS AND NOTHING ELSE heh)

Comment: Yes, I know about nesting using blocks, but this only works if you've got a single line underneath. In most of my code, that is not the case. Still a very helpful post overall... learned a few things (+1)

Comment: @Cyborgx37 yeah I realize the scope nesting only works f you don't have extra bits, that said is there a pattern to the manner of your usings? Would it perhaps be viable to move some of that extra into the constructor if it's at the top or the disposal if it's at the bottom? That is if it's patterned; guessing it might be since you brought this up as an issue, so you probably run into these using nests often in your code.

Comment: I've actually started work on a Factory-pattern implementation which wraps COM objects in an "AutoCleanup" class. I then use a single `using` statement on the factory class and, when it is disposed, it automatically disposes all of the wrapped up classes. It's working well so far and has significantly reduced the number of `using` statements in my code.

Comment: I've also implemented an "ExtractSingleValue" extension method which allows me, via a lambda statement, to extract a value from a COM object then immediately dispose it. This has eliminated the need for many of my `using` statements.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the oldest causes of warfare in computing, unfortunately.  Reasonable arguments can be made from both sides (better vertical real-estate economy versus easier ability to visually match opening brace with closing brace), but in reality a simple source-code formatter will resolve everything for you.  MS Visual C# has one built in that works well.

Be warned however that if you are working as part of a team you will be expected to conform to the conventions used by that team, so it pays to gain some familiarity with both styles and to refrain from getting religious over brace styles.

So while you're learning by all means focus on the style that makes it easier for you to learn, but keep half an eye on the other while you're at it and you'll do fine.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the default formatter or something in ReSharper, but when I used to use C# we had an option set that reformatted the code as part of the check-in.  That way you could format the code however you wanted while you were working with it, but it would be reformatted to "project standard" on check-in.  I think the only real formatting standard we had was to use spaces instead of tabs.

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on to the editor that may help you at: [C# Outline](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4d7e74d7-3d71-4ee5-9ac8-04b76e411ea8).

The add-on extends the VS20xx editor for C# by adding features to collapse, expand and highlight nested blocks of code. These features allows for easier editing and reading of nested contents of code blocks such as if, while, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use Resharper, which will help recommend ways to reduce nesting. Also, read Bob Martin's book *Clean Code*, which emphasizes that a function should only do one thing, and therefore each function should only be a half-dozen lines long, so you won't have that many levels of nesting to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your Code in Visual Studio, there's also a Plugin that shows you vertical dots between the beginning and the end of every structure that you construct.

But overall I think it'll just take some time until you're used to the "Curly-Braces-Soup". (Btw, I really like that expression. Sounds a bit like a Episode-Name for The Big Bang Theory)

Answer (score 0):

Indentation tells you where you are, in both styles of syntax. If you write either a VB program or a C# program on a single line, you will soon not be able to tell where in the nested syntax you are. The machine parses the block ending phrases or curly braces, but humans need indentation.

Block ending phrases come from an era of punched cards and paper tape, when programming was much less interactive and visual. Or, really, not interactive at all. It was difficult to enter programs, and so programmers needed compilers to be very clever about syntax analysis and error recovery.

In that bygone era, the edit-compile-run cycle might have involved preparing punched cards with a card puncher, and then lining up to a job submission window where a clerk took the punched cards and submitted them to the machine. Later, the programmer would collect the output (printed on paper) from another window. If the program had errors, the output would consist of just the compiler diagnostics.  When the turnaround times are long, the added cost of typing `end if` instead of just `)` is justified if it helps to improve the quality of diagnostics, because the programmer needs to correct as many errors as possible in a single iteration to reduce the number of time-wasting iterations through the job submission window.

When a closing curly brace is missing, it is hard to tell which open brace is the one which is not closed. (The compiler may have to parse indentation to make an educated guess.) If you delete a closing brace inside a function, then it looks like the entire rest of the file is part of that function, resulting in a flurry of unhelpful error messages.  Whereas if you have an `end function` syntax, the compiler can deduce where the erroneous function ends, recover, and parse the subsequent functions properly, giving you additional diagnostics, if any, which are meaningful.

When you're working in code-aware text editor which automatically indents and colorizes your code, on a high resolution screen where you can see sixty or more lines, the arguments for those kinds of clumsy languages no longer apply. You can incrementally edit and rebuild programs so fast that you can just deal with one error at a time. Moreover, by seeing large sections of the program simultaneously on the screen and maintaining proper indentation, you can reduce the occurrence of those kinds of nesting errors in the first place. And good programming text editor will even flag some kinds of syntax errors as you type. What is more, there are folding editors which will collapse the blocks of a program based on its syntax, giving an "outline-like" view of its structure.

Lisp used parentheses from the beginning and perhaps, not coincidentally, Lisp hackers pioneered programming as an interactive experience by building systems which accepted programs in small chunks (expressions).

In fact, you don't need ending symbols at all, as the Python language illustrates. The  identation can just *be* the structure. Humans already use indentation to grok the structure of code even in languages where the machine relies on ending symbols or phrases.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using an IDE, Just press <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and the IDE will do the rest of the work.

Comment: which IDE eclipse uses ctrl-shift-i for indentation and ctrl-shift-f for formatting

Comment: check in visual studio